# Remove rows based specific condition

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
  name   keyword1  keyword2  keyword3 
  artA      0         1         0 
  artA      1         1         0  
  artB      0         0         1
  artB      1         1         0  
  artC      1         1         0 
  artD      0         0         0 
  artD      0         0         0
```

How is it possible to remove SUM rows  based on column name?

Expression:

```
df <- df$name[rowSums(df$name != 0)>0,]
```

Expected results:

```
name keyword1  keyword2  keyword3 
artA    0         1         0 
artA    1         1         0  
artB    0         0         1
artB    1         1         0  
artC    1         1         0
```

Comment: `df[!rowSums(df[,2:4])==0,]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `Reduce`

```
df1[Reduce(`|`, df1[-1]),]
#    name keyword1 keyword2 keyword3
#1 artA        0        1        0
#2 artA        1        1        0
#3 artB        0        0        1
#4 artB        1        1        0
#5 artC        1        1        0
```

Comment: thank you if I want to cut rows >10 I tried this `df1[Reduce(`|`, df1[-1]) >10,]` but I think it is not right

Comment: @Kari  YOu need `df1[Reduce("|", lapply(df1[-1], ">", 10)),]` Your condition is not clear in this case

Comment: @Keri In your example dataset, there is no value that is greater than 10.  So you get 0 rows